# Creating Python Email (receiving) server

Tags: python, linux, email, smtp

I am trying to produce a simple python script for a Linux VPS that will allow me to receive mail, (and then I can do stuff to it in python, like print it to stdout). Nothing more complex than that.

I don't want to use a 'heavy' solution or server program, I am really just after a simple python script that I can run, and is capable of receiving mail.

Will Pythons' smtpd module suffice for this task? I have heard conflicting opinions thus far. If not, what else would you suggest? Perhaps you have hacked together some code yourself?

At this stage, even projects like lamson seem too heavy (though this may be unavoidable if I cannot find a better solution).

Comment: Here is an example with smtpd: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2008/10/pymotw-smtpd.html If you don't intend to host your mail server publicly and it fulfills your needs, I don't see any problem with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pythons smtpd is sufficient.

You might also want to take a look at [inbox.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz/inbox.py) and [this example](https://github.com/kennethreitz/inbox.py/issues/3#issuecomment-5606161)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the information I am after. When I read inbox.py and saw this "This is simplest SMTP server you'll ever see. One instance should handle over one thousand emails per second." I exploded.

Answer (score 8):

Yes SMTPD Module will be help full.
[Example code is here](http://pymotw.com/2/smtpd/):

> ```
> import smtpd
> import asyncore
>
> class CustomSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):
>
>     def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
>         print 'Receiving message from:', peer
>         print 'Message addressed from:', mailfrom
>         print 'Message addressed to  :', rcpttos
>         print 'Message length        :', len(data)
>         return
>
> server = CustomSMTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 1025), None)
> asyncore.loop()
> ```

Comment: How can I test it?? What mail address is listening and I should use to receive mails??

Comment: I realised I could connect to it using telnet. telnet 127.0.0.1 1025

Comment: The method signature should be ``def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data, mail_options=None, rcpt_options=None):`` to prevent some exceptions.